Duplicate value with id that doesn't exist in another table
I have 2 tables in Oracle:
Recipient:



id_recipient
email
editor_id




1
bob@gmail.com
1


2
bob@gmail.com
1


3
jean@gmail.com
5


4
joe@gmail.com
3


5
bob@gmail.com
4


6
paul@gmail.com
1



RecipientDeposit:



id_recipient
id_deposit




3
1


4
2



I search to select every row in recipient (with same email and same editor) that doesn't have any value in recipientDeposit.
With that query, I get recipient that doesn't exist in RecipientDeposit
SELECT 
    re.id_recipient , re.editor_id, re.email 
FROM 
    recipient re 
WHERE 
    re.id_recipient NOT IN (SELECT rd.id_recipient 
                            FROM RecipientDeposit rd 
                            WHERE re.id_recipient = rd.id_recipient)

I tried that
SELECT 
    re.id_recipient, re.editor_id, re.email 
FROM 
    recipient re 
JOIN 
    (SELECT editor_id, email 
     FROM Recipient re2 
     GROUP BY editor_id, email  
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) b ON re.editor_id = b.editor_id 
                            AND re.email = b.email
WHERE  
    re.id_recipient NOT IN (SELECT rd.id_recipient 
                            FROM RecipientDeposit rd 
                            WHERE re.id_recipient = rd.id_recipient)

but I'm really not sure.

what is your expected output

id_recipient 1, 2

@roberttrudel Isn't that what your query gets after fixing some of the syntax issues (ex. da alias should be re, and there's an extra comma after email in the first subquery)? https://dbfiddle.uk/bwWjOaBZ

A [mcve] is supposed to specify the expected result too.

You can do it only querying the Recipient table once using analytic functions:
SELECT id_recipient,
       email,
       editor_id
FROM   (
  SELECT id_recipient,
         email,
         editor_id,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY email, editor_id) AS num_rows,
         COUNT(
           CASE
           WHEN EXISTS(
                  SELECT 1
                  FROM   RecipientDeposit rd
                  WHERE  rd.id_recipient = r.id_recipient
                )
           THEN 1
           END
         ) OVER (PARTITION BY email, editor_id) AS has_deposit
  FROM   Recipient r
)
WHERE  has_deposit = 0
AND    num_rows > 1

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE Recipient (id_recipient, email, editor_id) AS
SELECT 1, 'bob@gmail.com',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'bob@gmail.com',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'jean@gmail.com', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'joe@gmail.com',  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'bob@gmail.com',  4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'paul@gmail.com', 1 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE RecipientDeposit (id_recipient, id_deposit) AS
SELECT 3, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



ID_RECIPIENT
EMAIL
EDITOR_ID




1
bob@gmail.com
1


2
bob@gmail.com
1



fiddle

I said i want to search to select every row in recipient (with same email and same editor) that doesn't have any value in recipientDeposit. So recipient 5 should not be displayed because email and editor are not duplicate. Idem for id_recipient 6

@roberttrudel The explanation in your question is unclear. However, I have updated the answer to remove rows that do not have duplicate rows for the email and editor_id combination.

Use email and editor_id as a pair checking existance in Where clause subquery which finds the pairs having 0 count id_recipients in RecipientDeposit table ...
WITH  --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    Recipient ( id_recipient, email, editor_id ) AS 
      ( Select 1,   'bob@gmail.com',    1 From Dual Union All
        Select 2,   'bob@gmail.com',    1 From Dual Union All
        Select 3,   'jean@gmail.com',   5 From Dual Union All
        Select 4,   'joe@gmail.com',    3 From Dual Union All
        Select 5,   'bob@gmail.com',    4 From Dual 
      ), 
    RecipientDeposit ( id_recipient,    id_deposit ) AS 
      ( Select 3,   1 From Dual Union All
        Select 4,   2 From Dual 
      )

--    S Q L : 
SELECT    *
FROM      Recipient
WHERE     (email, editor_id)
                   IN  ( Select    r.email, r.editor_id
                          From      Recipient r
                          Left Join RecipientDeposit rd ON(rd.id_recipient = r.id_recipient)
                          Group By  r.email, r.editor_id
                          Having    Count(rd.id_recipient) = 0
                        )
ORDER BY  id_recipient

/*    R e s u l t :
ID_RECIPIENT EMAIL           EDITOR_ID
------------ -------------- ----------
           1 bob@gmail.com           1
           2 bob@gmail.com           1
           5 bob@gmail.com           4    */


seem there is an error, when i run it,  in the result, i see some email who are there... there are unique, but have same editor_id.. you query return ID_RECIPIENT 6 and should not

@roberttrudel Sorry, but there is no id_recipient 6 at all.
